# How do I handle flavor/target resources in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm building a React Native app which has multiple Targets/Flavors for iOS/Android respectively. So, I have the same code base for both App1 and App2, but they have different logos, launch screens etc.  I can't figure out how to add different images to the different versions.

My Android setup in `android/app/build.gradle` is:

```
flavorDimensions "appVersion"
productFlavors {
    app1 {
        applicationId="com.app1name"
        dimension "appVersion"
    }
    app2 {
        applicationId="com.app2name"
        dimension "appVersion"
    }
```

Then in `android/app/src` I have a `main` folder, and an `app2` folder, each of which contains a `res` folder which has the following structure:

```
res
 - drawable-hdpi etc
 - mipmap-hpi etc (logos are in here)
 - values
```

When I build app1, it uses the logos etc. from the `main` folder; if I build app2, it uses the ones from `app2` (if they exist).

Likewise for the Targets in XCode, I have 2 Targets, app1 and app2, and have set up the image assets so it pulls in the correct logo etc.

This works fine for the logos and launch screens, but how do I handle images which are to be shown in the app itself? So say the dashboard needs to show Image1.png for App1, and Image2.png for App2 - where should Image1.png and Image2.png be stored?

The main issue is that the image path in React Native can't be a variable. To show an image in React Native I have to use something like:

```
  <Image
    source={require('path/to/image')}
  />
```

I thought I could use a `switch` statement, so store image_app1.png and image_app2.png in a folder somewhere, and then do something like the following:

```
switch(appVersion) {
  case app1:
    imageName = image_app1.png
    break
  case app2:
    imageName = image_app2.png
    break
}
```

and then use `imageName` to create the path and then require it, but this doesn't work because the path can't be a variable.

The other solution I've seen is to require all images at the outset, and then just show the correct one:

```
const image1 = require('/path/to/Image1.png')
const image2 = require('/path/to/Image2.png')

switch(appVersion) {
  case app1:
    <Image source={image1} />
    break
  case app2:
    <Image source={image2} />
    break
}
```

but potentially that involves pre-loading quite a few images (I may later have more app versions, and some of these images might be quite big) and I imagine it could slow things down.

Is there a way to put the images into the appropriate folders in android / ios (so just call the image `image.jpg` or whatever for all versions, but have different versions in the different folders) and then just refer to `image.jpg` and let it find the correct one?  Or is there a standard way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You could use react-native-fs or react-native-blob-util (preferred one, since react-native-fs is no longer maintained), create assets folder inside your target folder and load images from there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).